# Repositing the generic lists dynamically

Tags: java, java-8

I have list of Generic Objects

```
List myList = new ArrayList();

Stirng a

B b //B is Object
class B{
    List<String> values;
}

Stirng c//

D d
class D{
    List<Integer> values;
}

myList //a b c d
```

Now I want to add like this

```
myList //a, b, values of b, c, d, values of d
```

For simiplicity I have written like this. My data is large, I need to do dynamically.

Can some one help me to do this Java8

Comment: I don't see any generics in your examples. Please clarify.

Comment: @Patan I am scratching my head wondering what you are trying to ask. This has hardly got anything to do with `Java-8`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. I have updated question. can you check.

Comment: @Patan Checked, still no clue.

Comment: so what have you tried and what problem(s) you faced?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<?> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();

String a = "String A";
B b=new B();
String c="String C";
D d=new D();
myList.add(a);
myList.add(b);
myList.add(c);
myList.add(d);
```